# The Transporter is a submonoid

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, algebraic-groups, monoid

I am reading Humprheys' Algebraic Groups, stuck at an apparently simple point

In section 8.2 Actions of Algebraic groups(line 6, paragraph 1), The transporter is defined:
Let $Y ,Z$ be subsets of $X$ (An affine variety of on which $G$ is acting regularly)

Define: $\text{Tran}_{G}(Y, Z) = \{ x \in G \mid x.Y \subset Z \}$.

The claim: $\text{Tran}_{G}(Y, Z)$ is a submonoid! I don't see why this is true,
if $a, b \in \text{Tran}_{G}(Y, Z)$ then $a.Y \subset Z$ and $b.Y \subset Z$ then why should $ab.Y = a.(b.Y) \subset Z$?

$b.Y$ need not be in Y!

Please give some hint.

Comment: When you say $\subset$, do you mean $\subseteq$ or $\subsetneq$?

Comment: I cannot find this claim after a brief search through a PDF of this section of the book. Can you give an exact quote / theorem number / page number / etc?

Comment: @Arthur the former

Comment: @diracdeltafunk line 6, paragraph 1, just after the transporter is defined

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thanks. Can u elaborate on your second point? I see that if the Transporter contains a point $x$ then it contains the entire coset $x$ of the stabilizer of $Y$.

Comment: I've looked again and still can't find the claim. Here's the paragraph I have: https://imgur.com/kmTmtnU. Is this also what you see? If not, what exactly does your copy of the book say?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I think you have a different edition in which the error has been removed..

Comment: @diracdeltafunk See this https://imgur.com/a/Avjxlfa